# How to pass a block of commands to a python subprocess?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an external application called `gmx` which works like so:

```
gmx trjconv -f test.trr -s test.tpr -o test.xtc -center -fit progressive -ur compact << eof
1
1
0
eof
```

This commands creates the file test.xtc in the current directory.

I would like to call this from a python subprocess. I tried the following:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(
    ['gmx', 'trjconv', '-f test.trr', '-s test.tpr', '-o test.xtc', '-center', '-ur compact', '-fit progressive'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
p.stdin.write(b'1\n1\n0\n')
p.stdin.close()
```

But it fails silently in the sense that no error occurs but nothing happens. I read some posts about passing eof but I could not adapt them to my needs. Would you have any idea about how to do this ?

Comment: What is supposed to happen? Are you checking stdout and stderr from your `Popen` object?

Comment: I could finally find a solution. See my answer below. Sorry for the incovenience.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the way my Popen was written. Rewriting it as:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(
        ['gmx', 'trjconv', '-f', 'test.trr', '-s', 'test.tpr', '-o', 'test.xtc', '-center', '-ur', 'compact', '-fit', 'progressive'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    p.communicate(b'1\n1\n0')
```

did the job.

There were at least two mistakes:

1. the arguments list must contain the arguments one by one (e.g. not
   `'-f test.trr'` but `'-f', 'test.trr'`)
2. using communicate when using both `stdin` and `stdout`